# How to use modulo and string correctly to translate a crypted sentence?

Tags: python, string, cryptography, modulo, caesar-cipher

I'm working on a project on codeacademy.com, in python. I have to use "Caesar code" to translate crypted words. I already have the answer but i don't understand it.
As you can see below :

translated_message += alphabet[(letter_value + 10) % 26]

+10 is there for the shift of the letters, but why modulo 26?
I tested with a subtraction and it also works. In the both way i don't understand why it's necessary and what modulo do ?

Thanks for your help !

```py
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
punctuation = ".,?'! "
message = "xuo jxuhu! jxyi yi qd unqcfbu ev q squiqh syfxuh. muhu oek qrbu je tusetu yj? y xefu ie! iudt cu q cuiiqwu rqsa myjx jxu iqcu evviuj!"
translated_message = ""
for letter in message:
    if not letter in punctuation:
        letter_value = alphabet.find(letter)
        translated_message += alphabet[(letter_value + 10) % 26]
    else:
        translated_message += letter
print(translated_message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

letter_value +10 can exceed the indexes in your alphabet array. Mod wraps it. Google "modulo arithmetic".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: Thanks, i understand it now, it's like a "protection" to not be out of range